# FAILED ASSERTION : LINE 205 POS 16 :IMAGEURL != NULL IS NOT TRUE

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When i run my flutter project i keep getting this error:

> Exception caught by widgets library
> 'package:cached_network_image/src/cached_image_widget.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 205 pos 16: 'imageUrl != null': is not true. The
> relevant error-causing widget was PostTile

My Code looks like this :

```
buildProfilePosts() {
    if (isLoading) {
      return circularProgress();
    } else if (posts.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/no_content.svg', height: 260.0),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "No Posts",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else if (postOrientation == "grid") {
      List<GridTile> gridTiles = [];
      posts.forEach((post) {
        gridTiles.add(GridTile(child: PostTile( post) ));
      });
      return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1.5,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1.5,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: gridTiles,
      );
    } else if (postOrientation == "list") {
      return Column(
        children: posts,
      );
    }
  }
```

Help me in resolving this error.
THANK YOU!

Comment: my post tile widget looks like this: `class PostTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Post post;

  PostTile(this.post);

  showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          postId: post.postId,
          userId: post.ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showPost(context),
      child: cachedNetworkImage(post.mediaUrl),
    );
  }
}
`

Comment: i update my answer,check this

Comment: This question should be improved to be helpful for others. Here is a good resource on how to write a good question [ask] and the importance of a minimal reproducable example [repro]. Community members please use "flag"/"close" votes to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

1).
**for ImageUrl check,**

```
class PostTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Post post;

  PostTile(this.post);

  showPost(context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PostScreen(
          postId: post.postId,
          userId: post.ownerId,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => showPost(context),
      child: imageCheck(post.mediaUrl),
    );
  }

  imageCheck(mediaUrl) {
    var imageUrl=mediaUrl.toString();
    print("image Url :-"+imageUrl);
    if(imageUrl=='null'){
      imageUrl='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
    }
    return cachedNetworkImage(imageUrl);
  }
}
```

i added condition for imageurl null also i print there.
may be helpful for you.

2).

**this code is for how to load .svg image.**

checkout your pubspec.yaml file,

are you added image path there like this,

[image]

```
new SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/fingerprint.svg',
  height: 20.0,
  width: 20.0,
  allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
),
```

Comment: yes i have added the assets in pubspec.yaml file still it isn't working it's showing in the terminal that error is caused by posttile.

Comment: ok, so you need to add code of posttile widget code here, i am get it that you get problem in svg image.

Comment: it still isn't working after updating the code.Still the same error imageurl != null is not true

Comment: so, check again